# How to you alias in dataadapter query?

Tags: vb.net, alias

I am using a sql server database and i am storing the time value in the datetime variable. I am developing a booking system application in vb.net. When I want to view already made bookings using datagridview and by implementing dataadapter and dataset...When the table is shown in the datagridview I want custom column names to be shown so can any one tell me that how can i use alias in the query given in datadapter initialization part

Answer (score 1):

In the query...

```
Select
   field1 as [First Name],
   field2 as [Last Name],
   ...
From
   table
```

In the code-behind:

```
dataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "First Name"
dataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Last Name"
```

In the designer:

```
DataPropertyName
```

Comment: I wasn't clear on what your question -- you called it "alias" -- so I gave 3 possible answers for that term.  I think it sounds like you're working in the designer, so in that case, just go to the properties, click on columns.  In the 'edit columns' dialog box, change the header text to whatever you want.

Comment: I utilized the 2nd method but it worked not by "Name" by "HeaderText" property...Thanks anyways for your help